# Closure of orbit of point of $n$-torus under translations is finite union of tori

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to do the following exercise

> Prove that for any translation $T_\gamma$ and any $x\in\mathbb{T}^n$ the closure $C(x)$ of the orbit of $x$ is a finite union of tori of dimension $k$, $0\leq k\leq n$.

I will use additive notation, here's my attempt:

Write $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n)$, if all $\gamma_i$ are rational, then $T_\gamma$ is periodic and $C(x)$ is a finite union of points ($0$-tori). Otherwise, take a maximal subset of $\{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n\}$ such that the elements of said set and $1$ are rationally independent (this is possible since at least one $\gamma_i$ is irrational, in which case $\gamma_i,1$ are rationally independent).

Without loss of generality let this set be $\{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k\}$, then the translation $T_{\gamma'}$ where $\gamma'=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k)$ on $\mathbb{T}^k$ is minimal and so a subset of $C(x)$ is a $k$-dimensional torus in $\mathbb{T}^n$.

The remainder of $C(x)$ is determined by $\gamma_{k+1},\dots,\gamma_n$. The same procedure can be repeated on $\{\gamma_{k+1},\dots,\gamma_n\}$ and must end after finitely many steps. So we are left with $C(x)$ being a finite union of tori of dimensions between $0$ and $n$ inclusive.

Is the idea correct? If it is, I feel as though I haven't made the last 2 paragraphs formal enough, so could someone please help me in doing this?